# Revit API Get the currentUIApplication

Tags: python, revit-api

Using RevitAPI through python interactive sheel

the code was working but now gets type None when I try to get the CurrentUIApplication

```
import clr 
clr.AddReference("RevitServices")

#import RevitServices
from RevitServices.Persistence import DocumentManager
from RevitServices.Transactions import TransactionManager
from System.Collections.Generic import *




doc = __revit__.ActiveUIDocument.Document
docTitle = doc.Title
uidoc = UIApplication.ActiveUIDocument
oo=DocumentManager.Instance
uiapp = DocumentManager.Instance.CurrentUIApplication
ii=app_

r = UIApplication.Application


app = uiapp.Application

print(type(uiapp))
```

Machine Windows 10
Revit 2021

APIDOCS https://www.revitapidocs.com/2021.1/fa185fce-a8e4-71e4-2b62-53fb83f5d304.html

Answer (score 0):

`ActiveUIDocument` is a property of the `Autodesk.Revit.UI.UIApplication` class, cf. the [docs](https://www.revitapidocs.com/2023/3488133d-60c2-aa7c-ab72-0d9360ff122a.htm). `CurrentUIApplication` is not part of the standard Revit API, but I would assume that it refers to the one and only `UIApplication` existing in a Revit session. Therefore, I would assume that `__revit__` itself is what you are looking for.

Comment: when I try to use __revit__.UIApplication.Application I get a type that has no attribute named Documents which I am using to iterate over the documents in the application it worked before through the DocumentManager but it just stopped working now

Comment: I do not know what the `DocumentManager` is. Nor the `CurrentUIApplication`. They are not part of the Revit API. If the object you are after is the current Revit API `UIApplication`, I suggest simply using the official Revit API objects to access it. It is definitely accessible using the `Document` and the `UIDocument`. I assume you are actually working within a standard Revit API context?